# CSV transformation all combinations of row columns

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file of names and variations of these names. The file looks something like this:

```
Abigail | Abby | Abbey | Abbie
Abraham | Abe  |       |
Aidan   | Aodh | Aiden |
```

etc.

I was wondering if there was a python script I could use that would pair these up for me as such:

```
Abigail Abby
Abigail Abbey,
Abigail Abbie,
Abby Abbey,
Abby Abbie,
Abbey Abbie,
Abraham Abe,
Aidan Aodh,
Aidan Aiden,
Aodh Aiden
```

ie getting every possible combination for each row. Has anyone any starting advice for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to turn your csv file into a list of list:

```
import csv

with open('csv.csv') as file:
    names = [list(filter(None, row)) for row in csv.reader(file)]
```

What you get :

```
names = [["Abigail","Abby","Abbey","Abbie"],["Abraham","Abe"],["Aidan","Aodh","Aiden"]]
```

Then you can do it quite simply like this :

```
combinations = []

for row in names:
    for i,n1 in enumerate(row):
        for n2 in row[i+1:]:
            combinations.append((n1,n2))
```

result:

```
[('Abigail', 'Abby'), ('Abigail', 'Abbey'), ('Abigail', 'Abbie'), ('Abby', 'Abbey'), ('Abby', 'Abbie'), ('Abbey', 'Abbie'), ('Abraham', 'Abe'), ('Aidan', 'Aodh'), ('Aidan', 'Aiden'), ('Aodh', 'Aiden')]
```

Comment: Thanks, just submitted an edit to add ```row = list(filter(None, row))```  to remove empty strings

Answer (score -1):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
import csv
def row_combo(d):
   return [[a, k] for i, a in enumerate(d) for k in d[:i]+d[i+1:]]

r = [k for i in csv.reader(open('file.csv'), delimiter='|') for k in row_combo(i)]
final_r = [[a, b] for j, k in r if (a:=j.strip()) and (b:=k.strip())] #clean data
```

Output:

```
[['Abigail', 'Abby'], ['Abigail', 'Abbey'], ['Abigail', 'Abbie'], ['Abby', 'Abigail'], ['Abby', 'Abbey'], ['Abby', 'Abbie'], ['Abbey', 'Abigail'], ['Abbey', 'Abby'], ['Abbey', 'Abbie'], ['Abbie', 'Abigail'], ['Abbie', 'Abby'], ['Abbie', 'Abbey'], ['Abraham', 'Abe'], ['Abe', 'Abraham'], ['Aidan', 'Aodh'], ['Aidan', 'Aiden'], ['Aodh', 'Aidan'], ['Aodh', 'Aiden'], ['Aiden', 'Aidan'], ['Aiden', 'Aodh']]
```

Comment: That's great thanks. To remove duplicates I just did ```mylist = [k for k,v in groupby(sorted(final_r))]```